# How do I add an xml file that I created in the setcontentview() function

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have created an `xml` file in my android project called `calc.xml`
but im not able to give my `xml` file in the `setcontentview()` function
what must be done?

Comment: you can call it like setcontentview(R.layout.calc)

Comment: be sure you are extending activity nd write this code in oncreate method

Comment: check with R.java you are importing it must be of your project package not android

Answer (score 1):

Normally this is the way:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.calc);
}
```

Post some code please, if your problem is still there.